# Pandas+seaborn faceting with multidimensional dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, facet

In Python `pandas`, I need to do a facet grid from a multidimensional `DataFrame`.
In columns `a` and `b` I hold scalar values, which represent conditions of an experiment.
In columns `x` and `y` instead I have two numpy arrays. Column `x` is the x-axis of the data and column `y` is the value of a function corresponding to `f(x)`.
Obviously both `x` and `y` have the same number of elements.

I now would like to do a **facet grid** with rows and columns specifying the conditions, and in every cell of the grid, plot the value of column D vs column D.

This could be a minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = [0]*4 # initialize a list with 4 elements
d[0] = {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[4,5,6],'a':1,'b':2} # then fill these elements
d[1] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':0,'b':3}
d[2] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':1,'b':3}
d[3] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':0,'b':2}
pd.DataFrame(d) # create the pandas dataframe
```

How can I use already existing faceting functions to address the issue of plotting `y vs x` grouped by the conditions `a` and `b`?

Since I need to apply this function to general datasets with different column names, I would like to avoid resorting on hard-coded solutions, but rather see whether it is possible to extend `seaborn FacetGrid` function to this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to go is to split the nested arrays first and then create a facet grid with seaborn.

Thanks to this post ([Split nested array values from Pandas Dataframe cell over multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372016/split-nested-array-values-from-pandas-dataframe-cell-over-multiple-rows)) I was able to split the nested array in your dataframe:

```
unnested_lst = []
for col in df.columns:
    unnested_lst.append(df[col].apply(pd.Series).stack())
result = pd.concat(unnested_lst, axis=1, keys=df.columns).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Then you can make the facet grid with this code:

```
import seaborn as sbn
fg = sbn.FacetGrid(result, row='b', col='a')
fg.map(plt.scatter, "x", "y", color='blue')
```

Comment: neat use of `pd.concat`!

Answer (score 1):

You need a long-form frame to be able to use `FacetGrid`, so your best bet is to explode the lists, then recombine and apply:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = [0]*4
d[0] = {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[4,5,6],'a':1,'b':2} # then fill these elements
d[1] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':0,'b':3}
d[2] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':1,'b':3}
d[3] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':0,'b':2}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.set_index(['a','b'], inplace=True, drop=True)

x_long = pd.melt(df['x'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(),
                 id_vars=['a', 'b'], value_name='x')

y_long = pd.melt(df['y'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(),
                 id_vars=['a', 'b'], value_name='y')

long_df = pd.merge(x_long, y_long).drop('variable', axis='columns')

grid = sns.FacetGrid(long_df, row='a', col='b')
grid.map(plt.scatter, 'x', 'y')
plt.show()
```

This will show you the following:
[image]

Comment: Great answer in zero time, I now understand the reason behind the need of using `pd.melt`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best, shortest and most comprehensible solution is to define an appositely created `lambda` function. It has as input the mapping variables specified by the `FacetGrid.map` method, and takes its values in form of numpy arrays by the `.values[0]`, as they are unique.

```
import pandas as pd
d = [0]*4 # initialize a list with 4 elements
d[0] = {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[4,5,6],'a':1,'b':2} # then fill these elements
d[1] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':0,'b':3}
d[2] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':1,'b':3}
d[3] = {'x':[3,1,5],'y':[6,5,1],'a':0,'b':2}
df = pd.DataFrame(d) # create the pandas dataframe

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df,row='a',col='b')
grid.map(lambda _x,_y,**kwargs : plt.scatter(_x.values[0],_y.values[0]),'x','y')
```

[image: seaborn faceting with lambda functions]