# How to split a cell which contains nested array in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas DataFrame, which contains 610 rows, and every row contains a nested list of coordinate pairs, it looks like that:
[image]

[1377778.4800000004, 6682395.377599999] is one coordinate pair.

I want to unnest every row, so instead of one row containing a list of coordinates I will have one row for every coordinate pair, i.e.:

[image]

I've tried s.apply(pd.Series).stack() from this question [Split nested array values from Pandas Dataframe cell over multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372016/split-nested-array-values-from-pandas-dataframe-cell-over-multiple-rows) but unfortunately that didn't work.

Please any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add a copy of your data that can be copy pasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my new answer to your problem. I used "reduce" to flatten your nested array and then I used "itertools chain" to turn everything into a 1d list. After that I reshaped the list into a 2d array which allows you to convert it to the dataframe that you need. I tried to be as generic as possible. Please let me know if there are any problems.

```
#libraries
import operator
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain

#flatten lists of lists using reduce. Then turn everything into a 1d list using 
#itertools chain.
reduced_coordinates = list(chain.from_iterable(reduce(operator.concat, 
geometry_list)))

#reshape the coordinates 1d list to a 2d and convert it to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(reduced_coordinates, (-1, 2)))
df.columns = ['X', 'Y']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did work! I am really thankful:)

Comment: Actually, it did work only for one of 610 arrays (one array looks like [[[1377909.0626 6696341.0589], [1377913.8088 6696326.7092], ... ]]]). But for my geometry_list which is already a list of 610 such arrays and has shape [array1([[[...]]]), array2([[[...]]]), ... array610([[[...]]])] it still doesn't work...

Comment: The problem is also that therse arrays have different lenghtes, so I get ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,115,2) (1,134,2) - array1 consists of 115 coordinate pairs and array2 has 134 pairs

Comment: well, i have modified a little bit your advices, and now it works)))) thank you very much:DDD

Comment: hey, glad that it works for you now :)) feel free to give my answer and upvote if you liked it

Comment: yeah, i tried to upvote, but i unfortunately don't have enough reputation to make my vote publicly visible

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use numpy. It allows you to perform a lot of list/ array operations in a fast and efficient way. This includes "unnesting" (reshaping) lists. Then you only have to convert to pandas dataframe.

For example,

```
import numpy as np

#your list
coordinate_list = [[[1377778.4800000004, 6682395.377599999],[6582395.377599999, 2577778.4800000004], [6582395.377599999, 2577778.4800000004]]]

#convert list to array
coordinate_array = numpy.array(coordinate_list)
#print shape of array 
coordinate_array.shape

#reshape array into pairs of 
reshaped_array = np.reshape(coordinate_array, (3, 2))

df = pd.DataFrame(reshaped_array)
df.columns = ['X', 'Y']
```

The output will look like this. Let me know if there is something I am missing. [image]

Comment: I try to get these coordinates from ArcGis.
It looks like this:
In:    geometry_list = []
        for rslt in out['features']:
            gm = np.array(rslt['geometry']['rings'])
            geometry_list.append(gm)
Out: [array([[[1377778.48  , 6682395.3776], [1377770.949 , 6682351.3558],...
It's a list with 610 arrays, each contains diff. number of coordinte pairs, presented as arrays also...

When I try to convert list to array, I get a following error:
coordinate_array = np.array(geometry_list)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (115,2) into shape (1)

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(500).reshape([250, 2])
cols = ['coord']

new_data = []
for item in data:
  new_data.append([item])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data, columns=cols)

print(df.head())

def expand(row):
  row['x'] = row.coord[0]
  row['y'] = row.coord[1]

  return row

df = df.apply(expand, axis=1)
df.drop(columns='coord', inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

### RESULT

```
    coord
0  [0, 1]
1  [2, 3]
2  [4, 5]
3  [6, 7]
4  [8, 9]


   x  y
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```