# copy rows in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find an easy way to break up the following dataframe:

```
COL_A COL_B COL_C COL_D
VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  OFFER1|OFFER2|OFFER3
```

to

```
 COL_A COL_B COL_C COL_D COL_Y
 VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  ...   OFFER1
 VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  ...   OFFER2
 VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  ...   OFFER3
```

Comment: Hope the link help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166359/how-to-unnest-cells-in-a-dataframe-employing-pandas-and-python

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `pd.concat`, `str.split` and `fillna`:

```
pd.concat([df,df.COL_D.str.split('|',expand=True).T],axis=1).rename(columns={0:'COL_Y'}).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Output:

```
  COL_A COL_B COL_C                 COL_D   COL_Y
0  VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  OFFER1|OFFER2|OFFER3  OFFER1
1  VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  OFFER1|OFFER2|OFFER3  OFFER2
2  VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  OFFER1|OFFER2|OFFER3  OFFER3
```

Comment: This looks very promising but I'm getting MemoryError with 520,000 rows or so. Is the memory intensive?

Comment: Not extremely, your rows maybe exploding due to the data.

Comment: I even cut it down to: Index             80
RO_NUMBER    4104184
VIN          4104184
offers       4104184
dtype: int64  and I'm still getting memoryError with plenty of memory